# how to add a varcahr column inside a json column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have two columns in a row

`Column1  Column2`

`"Lion"   {"a": 1, "b":2}`

I want a result like

`Column3`

`{ "a": 1, "b":2, "animal": "Lion" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the value with a new JSON:

```
select column2 || jsonb_build_object('animal', column1) as column3
from the_table;
```